# Can Spring webflux be used along with spring web mvc project?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-webclient

I want to use WebClient instead of RestTemplate but I need to add dependency org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux which a reactive framework for my non reactive project. Is there way to use web client from spring web?

Comment: Just add it as as dependency, you will have to tell your application that you are still using a SERVLET by specifing `spring.main.application-type` in your `application.properties`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add the webflux dependency and use the `WebClient` in your application. Spring Boot recognizes this usage pattern and [highlights in the reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#web.reactive.webflux):

> Adding both spring-boot-starter-web and spring-boot-starter-webflux
> modules in your application results in Spring Boot auto-configuring
> Spring MVC, not WebFlux. This behavior has been chosen because many
> Spring developers add spring-boot-starter-webflux to their Spring MVC
> application to use the reactive WebClient. You can still enforce your
> choice by setting the chosen application type to
> SpringApplication.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.REACTIVE).

Answer (score 0):

As of [Spring Framework] 5.0 the RestTemplate is in maintenance mode, with only requests for minor changes and bugs to be accepted. Please, consider using the WebClient which offers a more modern API and supports sync, async, and streaming scenarios.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webmvc-client.html